# Kendo UI Grid is not Supported Remote MVC Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have put mvc remote validation in model class and this remote validation method is calling which I have controller .It is perfectly working for mvc view but not working with `kendo ui grid`.

Please help me if anyone know about this issue.

My model code is:

```
[Required]
    [Remote("CheckDuplicateRoleName",
        "Role",
        AdditionalFields = "RoleId",
        ErrorMessage = "This Role Name already exists.")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    }
```

For mvc remote validation `CheckDuplicateRoleName` is method name which I had put in `Role controller` and `RoleId` is additional field .I want to display this `errormessage` in kendo popup for  check duplicate rolename exist in database .But this controller method is not calling .

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for remote mvc validation

```
 (function ($, kendo) {
        $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
            rules: {
                mvcremotevalidation: function (input) {
                    if (input.is("[data-val-remote]") && input.val() != "") {
                        var remoteURL = input.attr("data-val-remote-url");
                        var valid;

                        $.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            url: remoteURL,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: validationData(input, this.element),
                            success: function (result) {
                                valid = result;
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                valid = false;
                            }
                        });

                        return valid;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            },
            messages: {
                mvcremotevalidation: function (input) {
                    return input.attr("data-val-remote");
                }
            }
        });

        function validationData(input, context) {
            var fields = input.attr("data-val-remote-additionalFields").split(",");
            var name = input.prop("name");
            var prefix = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            var fieldName;
            var data = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                fieldName = fields[i].replace("*.", prefix);
                data[fieldName] = $("[name='" + fieldName + "']", context).val();
            }
            return data;
        }
    })(jQuery, kendo);
```